# Wix create subgroups in list repeater

Tags: javascript, velo

I want to create subgroups in a list repeater on a dynamic page on Wix. In other words I want to group items from a database based on a category. I would like to achieve a structure like this on one dynamic page (example countries):

```
Group Title 1 (e.g. Europe)

    Repeater cell 1 (eg. Denmark)

    Repeater cell 2 (e.g. Italy)

    Repeater cell 3 (e.g. Greece)


Group Title 2 (e.g. South America)

    Repeater cell 1 (eg. Brasil)

    Repeater cell 2 (e.g. Chile)

    Repeater cell 3 (e.g. Peru)
```

and so on.

So the structure of the cells is the same, I just want to add some kind of grouping of the elements based on a category.

How can I achieve this? Has anybody any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!